# Too many sessions on root apache tomcat when migrate SSL HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, tomcat, https, root

I was using an EC2 instance of AWS and deploy my app on root through HTTP.
Now I migrated to HTTPs but the app does not load correctly. But I cant see any errors on chrome developers tools. The only thing I noticed different is that there is a lot of connections (350) made to the root that is where I deployed the app. I suspect is because the change of https. To made my app HTTPs I am using a load balancer of AWS and the aws certificate manager. Sorry for my english.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9ARp.jpg)

Comment: Where are you seeing the 350 connections? Apache? Enable ALB/ELB access logs, they might tell a story.

Answer (score 1):

when you add SSL certificates to the Application Load Balancer, the encryption and decryption of the request is taken care of by the ALB. Read more about this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html). This means that your app can operate normally and should not be concerned with the request policy.

You can create a target group and point both HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) traffic to the same target group.

Coming to your question. It seems like you are having difficulty in connecting to the ALB on port 443 (HTTPS). If your application is working as expected on port 80 (HTTP) follow this checklist to zero down on your problem:

1. Make sure that the security group of the ALB allows port 443 to your users or to the world
2. Check if the ALB has a listener configured on port 443. Read more about this in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html)
3. Check if this listener points to the application target group.
4. As a last step, if you are using a domain name, make sure that it is pointing to the ALB and not the origin servers (EC2 in this case)

If you would like to get better understanding of how the request flows from the users instance to your application server, I've answered a simmilar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845276/https-on-ec2-instance-running-python-project/62845465#62845465).

Comment: Thaks for the answer. But I had made worked the app on 443. I have already gotten the certificate. But it looks like a problem of HTML and CSS, I didnt change anything else, and like I said there is no errors on chrome debug. But the only thing different is that there is like 350 connections to the root app, and my web that has a correct domain, I thing is impossible to have 350 users connecting because is no public yet. So I cant get where is the problem. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: If you do share more details, like the access log of the server, we can take it from there. With the details provided, it's not possible to point in any direction.

Comment: Also, the standard is to offload SSL processing to ALB. So essentially your server only has to handle HTTP protocol. This also reduces the load from your server which means you increase your capacity.